# Date format codes - where to find them in the documentation?

Tags: r

Where can I find the date/time format codes (like `%Y-%m-%d`) in the documentation? I tried to look at `?format.Date` or `?as.Date`, but I cannot find any references in the section describing the `format` parameter. Or is it hidden somewhere else?

Comment: In the help page of `strptime`.

Comment: "cannot find any references in the section describing the `format`"; see **Arguments** section / `format` in `?format.Date` or `?as.Date`: "[...] Otherwise, the processing is via `strptime`; **See also** section: [...] Your system's help pages on `strftime` and `strptime` to see how to specify their formats.

Comment: @Henrik, strange, I see no such note as "Otherwise, the processing is via strptime" in the **Arguments** section! Are we looking at the same help page? http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/as.Date PS: I insist there should be a reference to `strptime` in the description of the `format` argument.

Comment: @TMS, I look at help page in `R version 3.1.2`. I _think_ the reference to `strptime` has been around also in previous versions.

Comment: @Henrik nope, I have R version 3.1.0 and it's the same as in the above link. It must have been fixed right about now, which is great.

Comment: @TMS, I _entirely_ agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary documentation is found under:

```
?strptime
```

Comment: Thank you Ananda! I think the help page of `?as.Date` should be updated, do you know where to post this feature request? Possibly here: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/ ?

Comment: @TMS,see Henrik's comment -- I don't think it needs updating. The only thing that might have been nice is a link under "see also" to `strptime`....